# Is the set of complex solutions to $x^2+y^2 = 1$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/25/science/the-lives-of-alexander-grothendieck-a-mathematical-visionary.html?_r=0) about Grothendieck, Edward Frenkel states that the set of complex solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2 = 1$ is "a plane with one point removed."  I'm curious how this can be made precise. Since the plane minus the origin is $\mathbb{C}^*$, it can be viewed as the algebraic variety cut out from $\mathbb{C}^2$ by the equation $zw=1$.  Is Frenkel saying that these two varieties are isomorphic?

To be precise, my question is:

Are $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ and $\{(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : zw = 1\}$ isomorphic as complex algebraic varieties?

The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231894/why-is-x2-y2-1-where-x-and-y-are-complex-numbers-a-sphere) shows that the above subsets of $\mathbb{C}^2$ are homeomorphic, but it's not at all clear to me how one would find polynomial functions realizing this homeomorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean polynomial functions like $z = x + iy$, $w = x - iy$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for! In retrospect, it was easy.  Maybe I was mislead by the answer to the question linked about, which was aimed at describing this variety as a cylinder.  Anyway, I guess the trick here is that in the complex plane, a sum of squares is also a difference of squares, and hence factors in the usual way.  This came up in a Putnam exam practice session recently.  A useful trick.

Comment: For completeness, I guess it's worth saying that the inverse isomorphism is given by x=(z+w)/2, y = (z-w)/2i.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint.* Substituting $iy$ for $y$ transforms $x^2+y^2=1$ into $x^2-y^2=1$, i.e. $(x+y)(x-y)=1$. Now let $z=x+y$ and $w=x-y$.